# Jekyll level 3 submenu

Tags: arrays, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'd like to make a three level submenu using jekyll pages.

First, i created folder that way:

```
Menu item 1 
 • menu item 1.1
   • menu item 1.1.1
 • menu item 1.2
   • menu item 1.2.1
Menu item 2
 • menu item 2.1 
   • menu item 2.1.1
   • menu item 2.1.2
   • menu item 2.1.
 • menu item 2.2
```

and so on.

For now, my files are in folder to use this kind of link:

menuLevel1/menuLevel2/file.md

I thought i could use YAML variables to do so, but it looks like i can't render an array of all variables in my YAML. I can make a menu using:

```
{{ if page.menuLevel1 == "foo" and page.menulevel2 == "bar" }}
```

but i'm stuck with sorting item, and since i have 5 level1 option and 10 level2 options, i think it'll take a long time to make it work.

Is there any way of doing this without hassle?

I don't where to go from here.

Tahnks a lot guys.

Ju

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, working with data-files is an option for you. Simply define a file `menu.yml` in `_data`-folder which contains your menu structure:

```
- title: "Menu item 1"
  href: "/menuLevel1/file.md"
  sub:
    - title: "menu item 1.1"
      href: "/menuLevel1/menuLevel2/file.md"
...
- title: "Menu item 3"
  href: "/menuLevel1/file2.md"
```

in your layout or include you walk through that file with for-loops:

```
<!-- 1st level -->
{% for nav in site.data.menu %}

  {% if nav.sub != null %}

    <li>
      <ul>
        <!-- 2nd level -->
        {% for sub in nav.sub %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ sub.href }}">
            {{ sub.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>

  {% else %}

    <li>
      <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ nav.href }}">{{ nav.title }}</a>
    </li>

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Working with several sub-menus you would have to add another level (i.e. 3rd for loop). Alternativly you can avoid redundancy in code by using an include with a parameter (`{% include param="level" %}` and level=site.data.menu, nav.sub,...) which calls itself with different parameter, whenever a sub-menu is found.

I use something similar than that for generation of a navigation menu. Simply works, i can sort the menu whenever i want and i have all my configuration files together with other files in my _data-dir (you could even store everything in _config.yml - i like to work with _data).

Hope i could help...